# edit my get first image function

Tags: wordpress

in my wp_theme i have this function to get first image of post as thumbnail

```
function get_first_image() {
global $post;
$first_img = '';
preg_match_all( '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', do_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ), $matches );
  $first_img = isset( $matches[1][0] ) ? $matches[1][0] : null;

if ( empty( $first_img ) ) {
        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/empty.png'; // path to default image.
}

    // Now we have the $first_img but we want the thumbnail of that image.
    $explode = explode( '.', $first_img );
    $count = count( $explode );
    $size = '-150x150'; // Our panel ratio (2:1) 312x156 for lighther page, 624x312 for retina; use add_image_size() and Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin when changing sizes.
    $explode[ $count -2 ] = $explode[ $count -2 ] . '' . $size;
    $thumb_img = implode( '.', $explode );
    return $thumb_img;}
```

but some image have custome size and this function not work on this case

like this :
https://yawar.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/yawar-1024x682.jpg

how can i force change the url of images that have another size ?

Answer (score 1):

The WP codex page regarding thumbnails says that you can specify your own sizes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails Look under "Add New Post Thumbnail Sizes". Maybe that will point you in the right direction.

Other than that, what about not specifying the size at all? Then maybe the browser would display the image at its natural size?

Comment: thanks . But i know about this function to get thumbnail in wp .
but my new function is for case that user don't set any thumbnail for post .

Comment: It might be because you're using a URL that doesn't exist. Can you verify that the URL you're using actually points to an image file?

Comment: yes . some url maybe havnt an image . and i want a code to detect this problem and set my default image in this case .

Comment: Well you might want to do it via functions.php. These tutorials both have a similar way of going about it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it/